# How to determine the mainloop behaviour for a canvas?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I can not wrap my head around what is wrong in this approach.

If you run this code, then a canvas with a black screen appears and if I uncomment `app.mainloop()` in the Screen class then a canvas with the image appears (which is expected).

Only thing being different in these two scenarios is where I start the mainloop whether in the Application class or the subclass. Am I missing something?

```py
import tkinter

from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Screen:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.width, self.height = app.winfo_screenwidth()//2, app.winfo_screenheight()//2
        app.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (self.width, self.height))

        app.bind("<Escape>", lambda x: (x.widget.withdraw(), x.widget.quit()))

        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(app, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.configure(background="black")

        image = Image.open("<IMAGE_PATH>")
        resized_image = self.resize_image(image)
        resized_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
        _ = self.canvas.create_image(self.width / 2, self.height / 2, image=resized_image)
        # app.mainloop()

    def resize_image(self, image):
        width, height = image.size
        ratio = min(self.width / width, self.height / height)
        width = int(width * ratio)
        height = int(height * ratio)
        return image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)


class Application(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.screen_widget = Screen(self)
        print('running')
        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application()
```

Comment: It is because if you comment the line, `resized_image` will be garbaged once exiting `__init__()` function.  But if you uncomment the line, then `__init__()` will not exit and `resized_image` will not be garbaged.

Comment: Thank you @acw1668. That did work if I persisted the image.
Also I was under the impression that when you create an image over canvas it is still referenced by the canvas. Anyways thanks for the help :)